# qsub: What is the standard when to get occasional updates on a submitted job?

Tags: qsub, torque

I have just begun using an HPC, and I'm having trouble adjusting my workflow.

I submit a job using `qsub myjob.sh`. Then I can view the status of the job by typing `qstat -u myusername`. This gives me some details about my job, such as how long it has been running for.

My job is a python script that occasionally prints out an update to indicate how things are going in the program. I know that this will instead be found in `outputfile` once the job is done, but how can I go about monitoring this program as it runs? One way it to print the output to a file instead of printing to screen, but this seems like a bit of a hack.

Any other tips on imporving this process would be great.

Comment: batch processing has not change much since the 1990s. Your plan to print output to file is perfectly legit.